# Array instead of List in WCF Service Proxy Generated using svcutil.exe

Tags: arrays, wcf, generic-list, proxy-classes

I have a `ServiceContract`,

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;
namespace MainModule.Sub.Communication
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWebMethod
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
        bool InvokeAlert(List<int> userIds);

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, Name = "InvokeAlertByMainID")]
        bool InvokeAlert(List<int> userIds, int mainId);

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void DeletePopupNotifications(System.Data.DataSet deletedNotifications);
    }
}
```

I used below command to generate proxy (I have to do this using `command-line` not via `Add Service Reference`.

```
SvcUtil.exe http://localhost/MainCommunicationServer/wm  /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1 /out:HTTPRouterServerProxy.cs
```

Even I added the `ct` switch (collectionType) the proxy is Generating it as Array (`int[]`). How can I do that without using `Add Service Reference` window in VS

Comment: Here you have the same question


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493376/why-does-wcf-return-myobject-instead-of-listt-like-i-was-expecting

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the /ct switch may not have any effect (in some circumstances?) on OperationContract-level collections. Try using a wrapper DataContract type, e.g. `bool InvokeAlert(InvokeAlertRequest r);` where `InvokeAlertRequest` will be a `[DataContract]` type containing one `[DataMember] List<int> userIds;`

Answer (score 0):

The /ct switch stops working if SvcUtil fails to create a proxy that uses the DataContractSerializer and uses the XmlSerializer instead.

This is just a guess but I suspect that `System.Data.DataSet` might be causing this.