# How to display List contents as a joined string

Tags: asp.net

I have a FormView that has a datasource bind as a object which is a  WCF service. In the WCF Service i have a Object PublicationDetail which has a attribute List authors;

I want to join the contents of the list and print them out in the form view however i fall on the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.

And the code:

```
<asp:Label ID="AuthorsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Join( ",", ((List<string>)Eval("Authors")).ToArray()) %>' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
String.Join( ",", ((string[])Eval("Authors")))
```

WCF serializes `List<T>` as `T[]` in messages, so your bound property is an array.

See [Why does WCF return myObject[] instead of List<T> like I was expecting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493376/why-does-wcf-return-myobject-instead-of-listt-like-i-was-expecting)

Comment: Mother of gad it worked i tried so many things and nothing worked till now : ) Thank you