# WCF type conversion

Tags: c#, wcf, list, generics, operation-contract

I am stuck with this error..can anyone point me in right direction
In my WCF service ..I have a operationcontract defined as follows...

```
  [OperationContract]
  [FaultContract(typeof(ProductFault))]
  BusinessResponse<List<Product>> GetProductList(int id);
```

I am calling the above method from a console application as follows..

```
LookUpServiceClient client = new LookUpServiceClient();

BusinessResponse<List<Product>> response = client.GetProductList(2);
```

But the lines `client.GetProductList(2)`;  is underlined with Red in VS2012. If I move my mouse over it ..I get error displayed as ..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, WCF proxy generation creates arrays for all collection types. So, you can fix this problem by changing your variable assignment to this

```
BusinessResponse<Product[]> reponse = client.GetProductList(2);
```

You can also change the default collection type generated by the proxy by choosing a collection type in the Advanced Settings (Array, List, ArrayList, etc.)

Comment: Thanks a TON. I spent almost 3 hours trying to explore myself the solution. Thanks again..apprecite the speedy reponse.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Dylan Meaodr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18280357/632337) has pointed out, WCF proxy generation creates arrays for all collection types.

Either way is to `change it to array assignment in your client project`

OR

you can tell the `service to use Generic list by configuring the service.`

Details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493376/why-does-wcf-return-myobject-instead-of-listt-like-i-was-expecting). Quoting from there -

> You can specify that you want to use a generic list instead of an
>   array by clicking the advanced button when you add a reference, or you
>   can right click on the service reference and choose configure to
>   change it in place.
>
> The reason is that WCF serializes Generic lists as arrays to send
>   across the wire. The configuration is just telling svcutil to create a
>   proxy that converts them back to a generic list for your convenience.

If you are adding a `Service reference` to your project, right click on your service and click on configure which will open configuration window for you where you can change the collection type -

[image]

Comment: Thanks I did the same

Comment: Updated the configuration for your service or the client code to expect array?