# Issue with what a function returns in my WFC service and Client

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am defining a number of functions in my client, as an example

```
[OperationContract]
List<CustomObject> GetObject(string id);
```

When trying to call this function from my interface if I try:

`List<CustomObject> result = cvs.GetObject(5);` I get an error, instead what I must do is `CustomObject[] result = cvs.GetObject(5);`

One other example is when I define a message:

```
[MessageContract]
public class TestRequest
{
     [MessageBodyMember]
     public Int64 Id;

     [MessageBodyMember]
     public int row;
}
```

and a function for my Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
ResponseMessage GetMessage(TestRequest req);
```

When I try to use this much in the same manner:

```
TestRequest req = new TestRequest();
req.Id = 2;
req.row = 1;
ResponseMessage resp = cvs.GetMessage(req);
```

I get the `there is no overload for method that takes one argument` message.

Below is the relevant part of the reference file created by

```
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
ResponseMessage MyService.GetMessage(TestRequest request)
{
    return base.Channel.GetMessage(request);
}

    public string GetMessage(long Id, int row, out long Length, out string Message, out System.IO.MemoryStream ReportMemoryStream)
    {
        TestRequest inValue = new ResponseMessage();
        inValue.Id = Id;
        inValue.row= row;
        ResponseMessage retVal = ((MyService)(this)).GetMessage(inValue);
        Length = retVal.Length;
        Message = retVal.Message;
        ReportMemoryStream = retVal.ReportMemoryStream;
        return retVal.FileName;
    }
```

Why is this disconnect between client and wfc service happen, and how can I solve it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a question on here already with some answers that explain the 'disconnect' as you call it between the client and the service:

[Why does WCF return myObject[] instead of List like I was expecting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493376/why-does-wcf-return-myobject-instead-of-listt-like-i-was-expecting)

Hopefully this is what you are after.

Comment: This solves the issue with lists, but not the issue with my custom message.

Comment: Any reason why you are using a MessageContract rather than a DataContract? Also out of interest, if you are using Visual Studio, what is the IDE expecting the method definition to be?

Comment: No idea actually, I simply wanted to also use MessageContract once since I am trying to learn as many secrets as I can .)

Also updated the question, I believe it will answer your other question.

Comment: I have to admit, I've never really used MessageContract so don't know much about it (except that it's something to do with controlling the headers as well as the data) - hopefully somebody else will come by and explain! I would be tempted to use DataContract in this case and see if that helps at all.

Answer (score 2):

Did you update the service reference after your last change of the method?
Looks like the proxy he generated isn't up to date.

Comment: Yes I did run `svcutil` to generate an updated reference file for my service.